# Settings to set a Screen Saver is not showing on Google Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

I’m developing custom screen saver for an android tv devices.
On Google Chromecast to set an screen saver there no possibility to do it in system settings, but it is possible to open with an intent

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setClassName(
    "com.android.tv.settings",
    "com.android.tv.settings.device.display.daydream.DaydreamActivity"
)
startActivity(intent)
```

After OS Update (OS version 10, 1 May 2022) this intent is presented, but doing nothing.
Start activity is called but nothing is happened.

I checked also similar apps, like PhotoGalery, Dreamy and there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from Google after opening issue there. Seems like there no possibility to set custom screen saver on Google Chrome device.

> Due to policy issues, this activity would finish itself when launched
> for GTV device. Only for ATV device, we allow this Activity to be
> launched and rendered

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240975577?pli=1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33086684)